# How to extract Firebase data to variable after setState() with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

First time using react and firebase real-time database. I'm having a hard time extracting the data and inserting it into const items. From my understanding, the firebase code is asynchronous, so the code will execute after the page is loaded up.

After checking the console numerous times, I see the data loads into const tasks array. However, the data inside tasks[] doesn't display when I put it inside the items array(title, subtitle, etc). I've looked at multiple solutions on this and none of them have answered my issue.

I thought it was because of the items being a const, but after changing it to var, the issue persisted. Any sort of guidance would be appreciated here.

One small note: using await doesn't seem to work for me whatsoever. I could be mixing things up due to my lack of knowledge of firebase + react.

```
const Timelines = () => {

    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const ref = firebase.database().ref();
        const listener = ref.on('value', snapshot => {
            const fetchedTasks = [];
            snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                const key = childSnapshot.key; //using await here doesn't work. Return 'await is a reserved word error'
                const data = childSnapshot.val(); //using await here doesn't work. Return 'await is a reserved word error'
                fetchedTasks.push({ id: key, ...data });
            });
            setTasks(fetchedTasks);
        });
        return () => ref.off('value', listener);
    }, [firebase.database()]);



    const items = [{
        title: "Header" + tasks,
        cardTitle: "Title",
        //url: "http://www.history.com",
        cardSubtitle: "LA",
        cardDetailedText: ["Paragrah"],
        media: {
            type: "IMAGE",
            source: {
                url: "./images/image1.jpeg"
            }
        }
    },
        {
            title: "Title",
            cardTitle: "Title1",
            //url: "http://www.history.com",
            cardSubtitle: "LA",
            cardDetailedText: "Paragraph 1",
            media: {
                type: "IMAGE",
                source: {
                    url: "./images/img-2.jpg"
                }
            }
        },
    
    
    ]
    return (
        <div className='timeline' style={{ width: "auto", height: "auto" }}>
            <Chrono items={items}
                slideShow
                mode="VERTICAL_ALTERNATING"
                theme={{
                    primary: "#7e8083",
                    secondary: "white",
                    cardBgColor: "#00467f",
                    cardForeColor: "white",
                    titleColor: "#00467f"
                }}
                useReadMore="true" />
        </div>
        
    ) 
  };

export default Timelines;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may be rerendering problem. So you can try loading state. Check my useEffect and return.

```
const Timelines = () => {

    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false); //<----


    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true) //<-----
        const ref = firebase.database().ref();
        const listener = ref.on('value', snapshot => {
            const fetchedTasks = [];
            snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                const key = childSnapshot.key; //using await here doesn't work. Return 'await is a reserved word error'
                const data = childSnapshot.val(); //using await here doesn't work. Return 'await is a reserved word error'
                fetchedTasks.push({ id: key, ...data });
            });
            setTasks(fetchedTasks);
            setLoading(false) //<---
        });
        return () => ref.off('value', listener);
    }, [firebase.database()]);



    const items = [{
        title: "Header" + tasks,
        cardTitle: "Title",
        //url: "http://www.history.com",
        cardSubtitle: "LA",
        cardDetailedText: ["Paragrah"],
        media: {
            type: "IMAGE",
            source: {
                url: "./images/image1.jpeg"
            }
        }
    },
        {
            title: "Title",
            cardTitle: "Title1",
            //url: "http://www.history.com",
            cardSubtitle: "LA",
            cardDetailedText: "Paragraph 1",
            media: {
                type: "IMAGE",
                source: {
                    url: "./images/img-2.jpg"
                }
            }
        },
    
    
    ]
    return !loading &&  (
        <div className='timeline' style={{ width: "auto", height: "auto" }}>
            <Chrono items={items}
                slideShow
                mode="VERTICAL_ALTERNATING"
                theme={{
                    primary: "#7e8083",
                    secondary: "white",
                    cardBgColor: "#00467f",
                    cardForeColor: "white",
                    titleColor: "#00467f"
                }}
                useReadMore="true" />
        </div>
        
    ) 
  };

export default Timelines;
```

Thank you

Comment: Hello, thanks for the feedback! Unfortunately, this did not work for me either. I print tasks[] in the console; it will show it empty, then once the page renders, it will show the snapshot.val()/key. When I attach tasks[] to the title of items[]. I'm still getting an [Object, Object] instead of the values. Ideally, I would like to assign task[0] to the title of items[] but it seems as if the value is not being assigned once the render is finished. It is for sure in tasks[] though. Please let me know if you need further clarification. My apologies in advance if I am not being clear enough.

Comment: I have also 2 alternative ideas. One of them,  Change forEach with snapshot.map. The other is that create an async snapshot function? Did you try them?

Comment: Yes, I have tried doing snapshot.map(data => ...) but it did not wor either. Same issue. I also have tried doing an async function and it resulted in the same issue where tasks[] holds the data but I cannot extract it to display. For the async function, I also tried putting it in the useEffefct() but no luck there either. I was confident that these solutions would work when I came across them but not sure why they didn't. One thing to note, when I `console.log(Object.values(tasks))`, the array shows up twice in the console. Once before the async code, and another after the code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

What Gökhan Geyik stated as a solution is correct. But I had to adjust my code a little since my Firebase db structure was different. The problem was, rerendering!

```
 useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        const ref = firebase.database().ref('Overview/events');
        const listener = ref.on('value', snapshot => {
            const fetchedTasks = [];
            const data = snapshot.val();
            fetchedTasks.push(data);
            setTasks(fetchedTasks);
            setLoading(false)
        });
        return () => ref.off('value', listener);
    }, [firebase.database()]);

return !loading && ( 
   ....
)
```

This worked like a charm. Much kudos to Gökhan Geyik for the right direction!